# Помощь с One Page Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Пытаюсь разобраться в [этом](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) плагине. Делаю всё по интрукции, но ничего не работает:(.

```js
$(".main").onepage_scroll()
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
}
html { height: 101%; } /* always display scrollbars */
body { font-size: 62.5%; line-height: 1; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; }

input { outline: none; }

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

a { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

body{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.first_block{
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.sirst_block{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>Main</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="onepage-scroll.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="first_block">
    </div>
    <div class="sirst_block">
    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Тут не будет работать инерактивно т.к нет ссылки на этот плагин в web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не работает потому что у вас один **main** элемент

Внутри **main** должен быть дочерные элементы больше одного чтобы данный эффект сработал .

В моем примере у `main` есть 4 дочерных секции `section` и к ним применяетсья эффект **one page scroll**

```js
(function ( $ ) {
 'use strict';
   $.fn.heightFull = function() {
 let totalHeight = $('window').height();
 let heightMinus = totalHeight;
 $(this).css('height', heightMinus);
  };
}( jQuery ));

$(".main .item").heightFull();
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".main .item").heightFull();
});

$(".main").onepage_scroll({
   sectionContainer: "section", // это часть берет любой селектор если вы не хотите использовать секцию поставьте другой html тег
   easing: "cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.420, 1.210)", // Опции плавности принимает только CSS3 свойства такие как "ease", "linear", "ease-in", "ease-out", "ease-in-out",или даже cubic bezier  "cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.420, 1.310)"
   animationTime: 1000, // Анимация дает вам определить сколько вы хотите анимировать каждую секцию 
   pagination: true, // Вы также можете спрятать или показать пагинацию 
   updateURL: false, // 
   beforeMove: function(index) {}, // это опция принимает каллбек функцию и будет вызвано ДО того как страница начнет скроллитсья
   afterMove: function(index) {}, // это опция принимает каллбек функцию и будет вызвано ПОСЛЕ того как страница начнет скроллитсья
   loop: false, // You can have the page loop back to the top/bottom when the user navigates at up/down on the first/last page.
   responsiveFallback: 600 //
   
   
});
```

```css
/***************************
COLORS
*****************************/
section:nth-child(1) {
  background: #2ecc71;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: #208e4e;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: #176437;
}

section:nth-child(4) {
  background: #0d3a20;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
  background-color: #208e4e;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
section span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body, .onepage-wrapper, html {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.onepage-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.onepage-wrapper .section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.onepage-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -48px;
}

.onepage-pagination li {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.onepage-pagination li a {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  display: block;
}

.onepage-pagination li a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

.onepage-pagination li a.active:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-top: -4px;
  left: 8px;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll, .disabled-onepage-scroll .wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper .section {
  position: relative !important;
  top: auto !important;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  -ms-transform: none !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-pagination {
  display: none;
}

body.disabled-onepage-scroll, .disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper, html {
  position: inherit;
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>

  <div class="main">
    <section class="item">
      <span><p>Page 1</p></span>
    </section>
    <section>
      <span><p>Page 2</p></span>
    </section>
    <section>
      <span><p>Page 3</p></span>
    </section>
    <section>
      <span><p>Page 4</p></span>
    </section>
  </div>
```